# Textview not not going back to orginal color after being unpressed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text view that I am setting the text color as follows:

```
<TextViw
android:id = "@+id/tv"
android:clickable = "true"
android:textColor = "@color/clickable_text"
android:textSize="16sp"
/>
```

And the selecor is

```
<item android:state_pressed "true" android:color = "#FF0000"  />  //which is red
<item android:color = "#00FF66"  />  //which is Green
```

The textview starts Green which is as expected. If I click (say hold on it) the color changes to Red which is good. But when release the click (i.e. untouch it). then the color changes to yellow!. Which is the default color android whould change a clickable view to upon clicking. WHY!!!!.

Shouldn't it come back to green to as I expected? The problem is that this color stasys on evenif I move between activities and come back
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: I tried your code (with small changes) and it works. Is your selector XML code in `<selector>` tag?

Comment: Yss i am putting it in selector tag

Comment: May be you're resetting text color somewhere in your code? XML looks correct (except `android:state_pressed "true"`, but it must be typo).

Answer (score 0):

You usually want to have a pressed, focused, and default state. And always put the default state last by the way. My guess is if you long press and then release, the button is not presssed (red), but is still focused. So change your focused to green as well as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color = "#FF0000" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color = "#00FF66" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color = "#00FF66" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Well if thats the case then it should stay red  .  I dont understand where it is getting the yellow (default color from)

Comment: Did you try it? Once you move your finger off, the button is no longer pressed, but it is still focused. Since you didn't provide a value for the focus, it is using the default color.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the exact answer for your question, but the idea from this link might help you: [Android how to make TextView text bold when pressed or focussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988850/android-how-to-make-textview-text-bold-when-pressed-or-focussed). I hope this helps you.